# No element found error when using $http service to post data to a local json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

Learning angular and in my app I have a local json file that I can use $http.get to read data from the file, but now I also want to post data to it.

For example my json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "old name"
}
```

And in my controller I am attempting to edit that name:

```
  var data = $.param(
      {"name": "new data"}
  );

  $http.post('testData.json', data)
      .success(function (data,status) {
        console.log("Post success");
      })
      .error(function () {
        console.log("Post failed");
      });
```

The error "no element found" appears in my browser console when it attempts the http.post. I'm sure it's pointing to the right file and that the json file is actually there.

Any advice?

Comment: Why are you posting to a json file?

Comment: I'm actually trying to post data to a real REST endpoint on a server but couldn't figure out how. So I figured it would be easier to learn how to do it right by getting a local example working. Since http.get works for reading the json I figure why wouldn't http.post?

Comment: You should be posting to a local endpoint, not a local json file.

Comment: You can use http://requestb.in/ for a free endpoint to post to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont forget to stringy the JSON!:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.hello = {name: "Boaz"};
    $scope.newName = "";
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                name: "new data"
            })
        });
        $http.post("/echo/json/", data).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.hello = data;
        })
    }                   
})
```

You cannot post to a local json file -- it just doesn't work that way. This is what you did in your code; see below.

```
 $http.post('testData.json', data)
      .success(function (data,status) {
        console.log("Post success");
      })
```

As noted, you posted to a local JSON file which -- as stated, just doesn't work.

You need to post to a local endpoint. See @jdersen's comment on the OP for using a https://postb.in/ to post your data OR set up or a local endpoint and try posting to that.

[**`Working Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/2872/)

Comment: You should probably explain that you did not make the endpoint a '.json' file.

Comment: I made an edit for clarification, it is awaiting peer review.